# HTTP2のHPACKの整数表現でオクテット境界の意味について

Tags: http, http2, hpack

http://syucream.github.io/hpack-spec-ja/header-compression-10-ja.html

「5.1 整数表現」で、

> プレフィックスサイズ N は常に 1 から 8 ビットの間です。 オクテット境界から開始する整数は 8 ビットプレフィックスを 持ちます。

とあります。
このオクテット境界から開始する整数とは何でしょうか？
その後の例では整数42がオクテット境界から開始とされていますが。

整数表現は32以上なら次のオクテットを使用する、と理解したのですが、8ビットプレフィックスが使用されるケースがよく理解できていないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この整数表現は, 1 オクテットに満たない他の情報と整数を同じオクテットにパックできるように考えだされたものです.  他の情報が MSB から X ビット使われているとすると, 整数表現で使用可能なビット数は 8 - X です.  この場合の整数表現法法を (8-X) ビットプレフィックスと定義しています. よって 8 ビットプレフィックスとは他の情報が存在せず, 整数が 1 オクテット全部使用可能ということです.

8 ビットプレフィックスを使用するケースは, ハフマン符号化が導入されるまでは存在していました.
5.2 文字列リテラル表現のString Lengthが, ハフマン符号化導入前は H ビットがなかったために 8 ビットまるごと使えたのです (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-header-compression-03#section-4.3.1). 現在は H ビットの存在のため 7 ビットプレフィックスとなり, 8 ビットプレフィックスの仕様書におけるユースケースはありません.
5.1 の記述は完全性を期して書かれているものとご理解ください.

Comment: ありがとうございます。
エンコーダを実装しようとしているのですが、8ビットフルで使うケースがよくわからなかったので助かりました。
いまだ仕様に使われないものが記載されているのは混乱すると思うのですが、完全性？のために必要なのでしょうか？

Comment: プレフィックスの意味を理解してしまえば混乱しないと思いますので問題ないと思います.

Comment: MSBに他の情報としてXビットが使われる場合と使われない場合があり、使われない場合は8ビットフルで使える。今はもっとも少なくてもHビットがあるので実質ユースケースとしては整数表現は多くても7ビットプレフィックスということですね。仕様としては記述があっても問題ない気がしてきました。
理解が進みました。ありがとうございます。